# Using functions on every row to return a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a big data frame with over 1000 rows. I am able to find the most similar rows to a certain index using cosine similarity and weight them accordingly. So my similar_rows data frame looks like this...

eg. similar_rows(60):

```
    A  B  C   Weight
0   5  6  7     0.2
1   8  3  2     0.3
2   1  4  6     0.1
```

I multiply each value by the weight column, and then find the average of all rows, so my result would be like so:

```
    A      B     C  
0  1.16  0.83  0.86
```

How can I apply this function to all 1000 rows so I'm left with a data frame like this for example:

```
      A       B     C
0    0.1     0.24  0.5
1    0.3     0.2   0.3 
.     .       .     . 
.     .       .     . 
1000  0.12   0.45  0.67
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use 'apply` function on the dataframe

Comment: Can you just show how do you get `1.16`. It will be  5*0.2 and then divided by what ?

Comment: I tried this but it returned 'positional indexers are out-of-bounds'. Is this because after I find the mean of the row the index is 0 for them all?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal It's (5*0.2 + 8*0.3 + 1*0.1) / 3

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `apply` function from `pandas.DataFrame` :

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply

You can make a function with it that will update every single row with whatever result you want by the same operations (just like the builtin `map` function on lists)

Also note that this function will be applied along an axis, so take care of which one you choose

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but it is returning 'positional index is out of bounds'. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @toothsie Can you show me the code you're trying to execute ?

Comment: Write code as answer,. Please post links in the comment section

Comment: @bigbounty at the time i didn't have the good reputation amount (50) to post comments, so i had to do an answer, sorry.

Comment: @bigbounty - it's fine to put links in the answer. I'd say, in fact, **do** put links in the answer - but only as additional material, and not as the main source. See. e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/1364007). It has a link, and it has code.

Comment: When I run the function for say index 25, it will return a single row with index 0, is it possible to return the same row with but with index 25 instead?

Comment: You can try this instead, this will maybe be better : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap
But normally, all the line is returned as is if you don't edit it inside your function

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np

df = df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,8,1],"B":[6,3,4],"C":[7,2,6],"Weight":[0.2,0.3,0.1]}) 
print(df)

Out[47]: 
   A  B  C  Weight
0  5  6  7     0.2
1  8  3  2     0.3
2  1  4  6     0.1
```

No need to use `apply` here:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'A':df['A']*df['Weight'],'B':df['B']*df['Weight'],'C':df['C']*df['Weight']})
print(temp)

     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.2  1.4
1  2.4  0.9  0.6
2  0.1  0.4  0.6
```

Next apply `mean` function

```
temp.mean(axis=1)

0    1.200000
1    1.300000
2    0.366667
dtype: float64
```

I have applied to only 3 values for each column.

Comment: Good solution, but you've put your imports before the codeblock and numpy is also useless in that case as much as i can see

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't seem feasible as I actually have 40+ columns (question was a simplified version of my data frame). And I am also looking for the average on columns rather than rows.

Comment: If you are looking for average on columns, then change the `axis` argument to `0`. I'll write the code and repost the answer